# Highmaps Group Countries and Hover, Follow link on Click

Tags: svg, maps, highmaps

As the topic states, I would like to group countries to create my own "areas". It works nearly, but I don't know whats wrong.

Here is my map: http://jsfiddle.net/wiesson/oktajn6e
It is mostly derived from the examples, but it does not work. If I set "allAreas" to false, it is okay but I would like to display all other countries, too!

Any ideas?

```
$(function () {
    // Instanciate the map
    $('#container').highcharts('Map', {
        chart: {
            borderWidth: 0
        },

        title: {
            text: 'Group Hover'
        },

        legend: {
            enabled: true
        },

        plotOptions: {
            map: {
                allAreas: true,
                joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
                mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world']
            },
            series: {
                states:{
                   normal: {
                        animation: false
                    }
                },
                point: {
                    events: {
                        mouseOver: function(){
                          var ser = this.series;
                          var data = ser.data;
                            $.each(data, function(){
                                this.setState("hover")
                            });
                        },
                        mouseOut: function(){
                          var ser = this.series;
                          var data = ser.data;
                            $.each(data, function(){
                                this.setState()
                            });      
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Nordic Countries',
            data: $.map(['IS', 'NO', 'SE', 'FI', 'DK'], function (code) {
                return {
                    code: code
                };
            }),
        }, {
            name: 'Some of central Europe',
            data: $.map(['DE', 'AT', 'GB', 'FR'], function (code) {
                return {
                    code: code
                };
            }),
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution should fix your problem: http://jsfiddle.net/oktajn6e/5/

But let me explain what happens in your code:

With both series you create a full world map with all areas. So if you activate both series, the second series covers the complete first series.

[image]

[image]

It means, the blue areas get covered by series' two grey areas.

I managed to solve it this way:

```
 series: [{
        allAreas: true,
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
        showInLegend: false,
    }, {
        allAreas: false,
        name: 'Nordic Countries',
        joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
        data: $.map(['IS', 'NO', 'SE', 'FI', 'DK'], function (code) {
            return {
                code: code
            };
        }),
    }, {
        allAreas: false,
        name: 'Some of central Europe',
        joinBy: ['iso-a2', 'code'],
        mapData: Highcharts.maps['custom/world'],
        data: $.map(['DE', 'AT', 'GB', 'FR'], function (code) {
            return {
                code: code
            };
        }),
    }]
```

By creating each series individually and setting "allAreas:false" we can simply render it on the first series, where we only show the full map.

Comment: Nice, but the country itself is in focus of the hover. Any further idea, how to disable the "country focus" and only allow the group hover?

Comment: It is only possible to focus single points. There is no hover event on series. So your approach seems to be right, but is somehow buggy. Here is a bug that might be related to it: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/2802

Comment: Thanks, I've solved this temporarily by using an other library http://jsfiddle.net/wiesson/5p2xhvb8/